# Pandas Rolling Conditional Count String

Tags: python, pandas

Given

```
   A
0  a
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  b
5  a
6  a
7  b
8  a
```

I wanna return a new column with rolling windows of 3 to calculate the occurrence of 'a' as follows, how to do that?

```
   A  Counta
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  3
3  b  2
4  b  1
5  a  1
6  a  2
7  b  2
8  a  3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rolling`

```
df['A_3_C'] = df.A.eq('a').rolling(3,min_periods=1).sum()
Out[413]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) as follows:

```
df['count'] = df['A'].eq('a').rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).sum()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   A  count
0  a    1.0
1  a    2.0
2  a    3.0
3  b    2.0
4  b    1.0
5  a    1.0
6  a    2.0
7  b    2.0
8  a    2.0
```

Notice that the last value should be *2* and not *3*.

If you want the output as integer, do:

```
df['count'] = df['A'].eq('a').rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).sum().astype(int)
```